# What is Valve Test Sub 74?

Tags: steam

Anyone have any idea's on what this actually is? I'm not fussed, but it's been on my account for years and I've no idea what it is.

Login to your account, http://store.steampowered.com/ , Then in the top right, click the drop-down and hit 'Account Details'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.themesshall.net/forum/showthread.php/6267-Valve-Test-Sub-74), it's an extended Portal demo.

Comment: Oh, fair enough :)